# How to integrate a finished React app into the Laravel web application framework

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8

There is a ready front-end built using [React](https://reactjs.org/).
*Is it correct to connect it?*

So far, there is only 1 page with one `div` block in which there are pictures. I read the documentation and didn't quite understand how it was done.

*Can you please describe in detail all the steps to enable it?*

I have a fresh/clean Laravel project. I don't know Laravel & React well yet. Therefore, I ask you to tell in detail and step by step all the actions so that React styles work in `welcome.blade.php`.

##### React structure (`src/index.js`):

```js
import React from 'React';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import 'macro-css';

const root = ReactDOM.creactRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image: React Structure]

I tried to migrate the code from React `index.js` into Laravel's `app.js` and I threw all the other files next to it in the hope that it would work.

[image: here's what happened]

Answer (score -2):

Please, first go through the [Laravel Bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/) which will take you through how Laravel integrates with [React](https://reactjs.org/).

[Writing Views In React / Vue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#writing-views-in-react-or-vue)

> Our Breeze and Jetstream [starter
> kits](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits) give you a great
> starting point for your next Laravel application powered by Inertia.
> In addition, the [Laravel Bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/)
> provides a full demonstration of building a Laravel application
> powered by Inertia, including examples in Vue and React.